# How do I convert Xml for display in html page

Tags: html, xml

How do I convert Xml for display in html page ?

By this I mean that if you open an Xml page in a browser such as Firefox it will render it nicely formatted as Xml. I want to put it into a Html file and have it displayed similarly. i.e showing the Xml with the xml tags and content, not converting into a table as some online tools I have tried do.

Comment: Use innerText rather than innerHTML.

Comment: @MrLister what do you mean isn't that Javascript ?

Comment: Yes. What method are you using to put the xml in a html file? Did you mean it is an xml file with a .html file name extension?

Comment: I mean I want to take some Xml and add it to a html file which contains some regular html so when the html page is dispalyed it shows the Xmlas Xml. It doesnt have to be dynamic I have an .xml file that I want to add to a .html file

Comment: You haven't said yet what languages or other tools you have at your disposal. With any HTML editor, paste the XML into WYSYWIG mode and then switch to source mode. Or purely by hand, use Notepad to change all `<` to `&lt;` and then add `<br>` to the end of every line. I mean, what have you tried? I'm beginning to think this question is too broad.

Comment: @MrLister okay that may work, whats a simple html WYWIG editor then